# Find the average age of people with a certain eye colour from a text file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the average age of people with a certain eye colour from a text file. The eye colour will be specified in a given question. This is what I have so far and it gives me the average age and the percent of each eye colours which is what I want, but I don't know how to now get the average age of people with a certain eye colour, so if I wanted to get the average age of people with blue eyes or green.

```
# Task 2
def opto():
    infile = open('optometry.txt', 'r')
    age_data = []
    count = 0
    total = 0

    for row in infile:
        if not row.startswith('#'):
            temp = ''
            for char in row:
                if char.isdigit():
                    temp = temp + char
            age_data.append(temp)
            count += 1

    for age in age_data:
        total += float(age)
    avg_age = round(total / count, 1)
    print(f"The average age is {avg_age}")


opto()


def colour():
    infile = open('optometry.txt', 'r')
    colour_dict = {}
    for row in infile:
        if not row.startswith('#'):
       # if not row.startswith('h'):
       # if not row.startswith('g'):
       # if not row.startswith('b'):
            temp = ''
            for char in row:
                if char.isalpha():
                    temp = temp + char

            if temp in colour_dict:
                colour_dict[temp] += 1

            else:
                colour_dict[temp] = 1

    for k, v in colour_dict.items():
        percent = round((v / 300) * 100, 1)
        print(f"{k}: {percent} ")


colour()
```

Comment: In the function that calculates average age, check if the eye color is the desired color before appending the age to the list.

Comment: May be worth including a small sample from your optometry.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the average age of people with a specific eye color, you can modify your code to calculate the total age and the count of people with each eye color. Then, you can calculate the average age for each eye color separately.

```py
# Task 2
def opto():
    infile = open('optometry.txt', 'r')
    age_data = []
    count = 0
    total = 0

    for row in infile:
        if not row.startswith('#'):
            temp = ''
            for char in row:
                if char.isdigit():
                    temp = temp + char
            age_data.append(float(temp))
            count += 1

    infile.close()  # Close the file before reopening for the next function
    avg_age = round(sum(age_data) / count, 1)
    print(f"The average age is {avg_age}")

    return age_data  # Return age_data for later use in the color function


def colour(age_data):
    infile = open('optometry.txt', 'r')
    colour_dict = {}
    age_by_color = {}  # Dictionary to store total age and count for each eye color

    for row, age in zip(infile, age_data):
        if not row.startswith('#'):
            temp_color = ''
            for char in row:
                if char.isalpha():
                    temp_color = temp_color + char

            if temp_color in colour_dict:
                colour_dict[temp_color] += 1
                age_by_color[temp_color][0] += age
                age_by_color[temp_color][1] += 1
            else:
                colour_dict[temp_color] = 1
                age_by_color[temp_color] = [age, 1]

    infile.close()

    for k, v in colour_dict.items():
        percent = round((v / 300) * 100, 1)
        avg_age_color = round(age_by_color[k][0] / age_by_color[k][1], 1)
        print(f"{k}: {percent}% | Average Age: {avg_age_color}")


# Get age_data from opto function
age_data = opto()

# Call the colour function with age_data
colour(age_data)
```

I added a new dictionary (`age_by_color`) to store the total age and count for each eye color. The `colour` function now calculates and prints both the percentage of people with each eye color and the average age for each eye color.